# Map Objects within an Object within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with an object inside that houses more objects that I would like to map to a simpler structure.

I have tried with the following and it seems to loop through the objects and return a single object for each loop with no data.

```
Object.values(data).forEach((a) => {
  console.log({
    managingRole: a.id === 110 ? a.answer : null,
    advice: a.id === 112 ? a.answer : null,
  });
});
```

The end goal is to return an array of object to map through like:

```
const desired = [{
  managingRole: 'spending',
  advice: 'everyone'
},
{
  managingRole: 'saving',
  advice: 'no one'
}];
```

The data I an working with is below:

```
const data = [{
  '110':
  {
    id: 110,
    type: 'RADIO',
    question: '<strong>My main role in managing my money is:</strong>',
    section_id: 9,
    answer: 'spending'
  },
  '111':
  {
    id: 111,
    type: 'RADIO',
    question: '<strong>When it comes to financial matters, I most agree with which statement?</strong>',
    section_id: 9,
    answer: 'spend it'
  },
  '112':
  {
    id: 112,
    type: 'RADIO',
    question: '<strong>When deciding on an investment, I trust the advice of :</strong>',
    section_id: 9,
    answer: 'everyone'
  }
 },
 {
  '110':
  {
    id: 110,
    type: 'RADIO',
    question: '<strong>My main role in managing my money is:</strong>',
    section_id: 9,
    answer: 'saving'
  },
  '111':
  {
    id: 111,
    type: 'RADIO',
    question: '<strong>When it comes to financial matters, I most agree with which statement?</strong>',
    section_id: 9,
    answer: 'save it'
   },
  '112':
  {
    id: 112,
    type: 'RADIO',
    question: '<strong>When deciding on an investment, I trust the advice of :</strong>',
    section_id: 9,
    answer: 'no one'
  }
}];
```

Comment: You mentioned the word "map" several times. Did you try `Array#map()`? A web search for "javascript map array" would have had this right at the top along with numerous questions on this site also

Comment: There's no need to use `Object.values(data)` to loop over an array. Just use `data.forEach()`.

Comment: You also need `Array#filter()` to remove the elements that you don't need in the result.

Comment: I don't really understand the relationship between the input and output. It looks like a single object in the output has properties from different objects in the input. I think they're related by having the same `id` property.

Comment: You need to use `Object.values(a)[0]` to get the property in the object. Why do you have an array of objects where each object has a different key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could address the objects directly with the given `id` which is the same as for the keys for the object with the wanted `answer`.

```js
const
    data = [{ 110: { id: 110, type: 'RADIO', question: '<strong>My main role in managing my money is:</strong>', section_id: 9, answer: 'spending' }, 111: { id: 111, type: 'RADIO', question: '<strong>When it comes to financial matters, I most agree with which statement?</strong>', section_id: 9, answer: 'spend it' }, 112: { id: 112, type: 'RADIO', question: '<strong>When deciding on an investment, I trust the advice of :</strong>', section_id: 9, answer: 'everyone' } }, { 110: { id: 110, type: 'RADIO', question: '<strong>My main role in managing my money is:</strong>', section_id: 9, answer: 'saving' }, 111: { id: 111, type: 'RADIO', question: '<strong>When it comes to financial matters, I most agree with which statement?</strong>', section_id: 9, answer: 'save it' }, 112: { id: 112, type: 'RADIO', question: '<strong>When deciding on an investment, I trust the advice of :</strong>', section_id: 9, answer: 'no one' } }],
    result = data.map(o => ({
        managingRole: o['110'].answer || null,
        advice: o['112'].answer || null
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```